# How to put an image on another image in python, using ImageTk?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to put an image in front of another one, then use this combined image as a button's background image in Tkinter.

How can I do it?

- I am free to `import Tkimage, Image`.
- Clarify: I want to stick this [image] on the center of this [image] so that something like [image] will be achieved!
  (I want to write Candy Crush! as a homework!)

Comment: Maybe the "down-vote-guy" thinks the answer is photoshop ... :D

Comment: I think you should explain more. If you don't want to alpha blend them, one will completely cover another, right?

Comment: @IronManMark20 you are right, it wasn't clear, and image.blend was a bad example. I edited my post with pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use photoshop or [G.I.M.P.](http://www.gimp.org/). I assure you, doing it that way will be much simpler and less redundant than essentially getting Tkinter to photo edit for you (not to mention what you're talking about is just bad practice when it comes to coding)

Anyways, I guess if you really want, it would be possible. Create a tkinter button with an image function (image="path\to\image.png") then assign it to a .grid(). For the second image, assign it to the **same** .grid() coordinants while making sure the overlay image is transparent. Here's an extremely general example since I've been given very little information to go off of.

```
Button0 = tk.Button(self, compound="top", image=.\path\to\BackgroundImage.png, fg="black", command=lambda: "call your function here"

Button0.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

Button1 = tk.Button(self, compound="top", image=.\path\to\TransparentCandyImage.png, fg="black", command=lambda: "call your function here"

Button1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
```

EDIT: You can also look for Python/scripts that integrate into GIMP (called "Script-Fu's") for performing batch photo editing. There are tons of out there that do all sorts of cool things but I don't know one off hand that will do exactly what you need. Here are some quick search results that look promising though:
*http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/
*http://registry.gimp.org/taxonomy/term/176
*http://www.sandyscott.net/2013/08/04/batch-editing-with-gimp-script-fu/

- Code is based off of my own Tkinter GUI: See here for source reference/code template: https://github.com/BiTinerary/AutOptimizer

Comment: The reason I wanted to prevent using photo editors was that I must cover too many cases since there are 25 * 2 different possibilities. So I must make about 50 pictures.

Comment: That is sometimes the amount of work that goes into creating an app. You can also look into batch photo editing using, irfanview (don't know if it does exactly what you want) or find a ScriptFu for GIMP that will batch perform the series of edit's you need.